# Can this property of the Gaussian integers apply to other rings like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has the property that an element of the ring is irreducible if its norm is a prime number congruent to 1 (mod 4). Also, it is irreducible of the elements are associates of the integers $p+0i$, where p is prime and p is congruent to 3 (mod 4). Are there similar properties for a ring like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: Great! Are they the same, or slightly different? I'm trying to find them but haven't had any luck.

Comment: Mod $8$ is, indeed, the way it works. $3$ and $5$ are irreducible, but $7=(3+\sqrt2)(3-\sqrt2)$ and $17=(5+2\sqrt2)(5-2\sqrt2)$ split into products of elements of a prime norm. A difference is that there will be many units, namely $\pm(1\pm\sqrt2)^n$. So for example as $(3+\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt2)=(5+4\sqrt2)$ we can also factor $7=-(5+4\sqrt2)(5-4\sqrt2)$. In other words, there will be infinitely many associates. Anyway, what happens depends on whether $p\equiv \pm1\pmod 8$ or $p\equiv\pm3\pmod8$.

Comment: Great! What about p=1? Is that a special case?

Comment: I'm an idiot nevermind!

Answer (score 0):

The general case is the [ring of integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer) in quadratic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$. The answer is not simple but is fascinating, See the book [*Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$*](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/primes.html), by David Cox.